# Get boundary pixel of contour alongside Major and Minor Axis

Tags: matlab, axis, boundary

So I have a contour with its Major Axis and Minor Axis plotted like image below

[image: Major Axis and Minor Axis Plotted]

Now, that I aware that major axis and minor axis doesn't stop at the contour's boundary, how I get the coordinate of boundary pixels alongside major and minor axis?

In this case it is the pixels that marked with red dot in image below

Thanks in advance

[image: Boundary pixels]

Comment: What if an axis intersects multiple pixels?

Comment: I don't know if that is possible, fyi I just do this for connected loop contour (like circles and ellipses) only

Comment: It is possible. Take a look at the lower left, a little bit lower and the axis would intersect two pixels.

Comment: If that's the case, the boundary pixel will be the first one the axis intersect from the centroid. In other words, the boundary pixel is the nearest pixel from centroid that intersect with the axis.